# Creation of WebSocket tunnel to guacd failed: Connection timed out

Tags: websocket, tunnel, guacamole

I'm trying to use this server  [test Server](https://github.com/jamhall/guacamole-test-server)for test purposes, I got my frontend up and running , with the following configuration :

this.manager = new RemoteDesktopManager(tunnel)

```
const parameters = {
    ip: '52.139.24.171',
    port: 3389,
    type: 'rdp',
    image: 'image/png',
    width: window.screen.width,
    height: window.screen.height,
    username: 'TestSavvyAdmin',
    password: 'TestSavvyAdmin!4',
    dpi :96

};
{address}&image=image/png&audio=audio/L16&dpi=96&width=n&height=n

this.manager.connect(parameters);
```

I also have my server running , but when I run the jar , I can have a connection to guacd and I get the following erroe :

```
C:\guacamole-test-server>java -jar target/gts.jar --guacd-host 1.2.3.4 -- 
guacd-port 4822 --port 8080

2019-06-25 12:20:10,389 [INFO] org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging 
initialized @200ms to 
org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
2019-06-25 12:20:10,507 [INFO] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty- 
9.4.z-SNAPSHOT, build 
timestamp: 2017-11-21T16:27:37-05:00, git hash: 
82b8fb23f757335bb3329d540ce37a2a26
15f0a8
2019-06-25 12:20:10,541 [INFO] org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - 
DefaultSessionIdManager 
workerName=node0
2019-06-25 12:20:10,544 [INFO] org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - No 
SessionScavenger set, using 
defaults
2019-06-25 12:20:10,546 [INFO] org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - 
Scavenging every 600000ms
2019-06-25 12:20:10,718 [INFO] eu.jamiehall.gts.ws.WebSocketTunnelModule - 
Loading Jetty 9 
WebSocket support...
2019-06-25 12:20:10,804 [INFO] 
 org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started 
 o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@229f66ed{/,null,AVAILABLE}
 2019-06-25 12:20:11,106 [INFO] org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector 
- Started 
 ServerConnector@2a5c8d3f{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
 2019-06-25 12:20:11,106 [INFO] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started 
@924ms
2019-06-25 12:20:19,119 [DEBUG] 
 org.apache.guacamole.net.InetGuacamoleSocket - Connecting to 
guacd at 1.2.3.4:4822.
2019-06-25 12:20:34,120 [ERROR] eu.jamiehall.gts.ws.WebSocketTunnelServlet 
 - Creation of 
  WebSocket tunnel to guacd failed: Connection timed out.
 2019-06-25 12:20:34,121 [DEBUG] 
 eu.jamiehall.gts.ws.WebSocketTunnelServlet 
 - Error connecting 
  WebSocket tunnel.
  org.apache.guacamole.GuacamoleUpstreamTimeoutException: Connection timed 
  out.
 at org.apache.guacamole.net.InetGuacamoleSocket.<init> 
(InetGuacamoleSocket.java:111)
```

any ideas about what I'm doing wrong ? thank you